# How do I select a subset of lines from the history in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, history

Quite often I `grep` through my bash shell history to find old commands, filepaths, etc. Having identified the history number of interest, I would like to see a few lines of context on either side, i.e. view a subset of history lines. For example:

```
$ history | grep ifconfig

8408  ifconfig eth0
8572  sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

I would like to look at the 5 lines or so either side of line 8572. Obviously knowing the line number I can page through the history with `less`, but this seems very stupid. As far as I can tell, the manpage doesn't seem to have this information either.

Is there a simple way to retrieve arbitrary lines of history in bash?

Comment: @Miky D: I don't think so - it's effectively part of my IDE. Eclipse questions seem welcome enough here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grep's -C option provides context.  Try:

```
$ history | grep -C 5 ifconfig
```

Answer (score 4):

```
history | grep -C 5 ifconfig
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to see it for specific line numbers, you can also use something like this

```
history | head -n 120 | tail -n 5
```

The example prints lines 116 through 120.

Answer (score 2):

```
history | grep ifconfig -A5 -B5
```

A = number of lines after the match found by grep
B = number of lines before the match found by grep
You can also change the number of lines from 5 to any number you want.

Answer (score 1):

type ctrl-r, then some characters (interactive searching). More [information here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_95.html).

Answer (score 1):

I type
 
  `history | grep " 840"`